# Adding columns with Variable names in SQL using C++, odbc

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, visual-c++, odbc

I am a beginner programmer and this is my first forum post, so please bear with me.

I'm using MS Visual C++ 2010 so send querys to MYSQL through an odbc connection.

So far I have had no problem inputing values into my tables but i'm struggling to create columns.

for example;

if this is how you input values into sql tables:

```
SQLCHAR  Col1[10];

SQLINTEGER ch1;

rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt,(SQLCHAR*)"(hStmt,(SQLCHAR*)"INSERT INTO phonebook ( LastName) VALUES (?) ",SQL_NTS);

rc = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, LENGTH, 0, Col1, 0, &ch1);

...// give ch1 and Col1 values

rc = SQLExecute(hStmt);
```

Then would I add columns the same way???

```
SQLCHAR  Col1[10];
SQLINTEGER ch1;

rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt,(SQLCHAR*)"ALTER TABLE phonebook ADD (? VARCHAR(45) NULL)",SQL_NTS);

rc = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, LENGTH, 0, Col1, 0, &ch1);

...// give ch1 and Col1 values

rc = SQLExecute(hStmt);
```

Please help. If you could post some example code with your response so I can better understand.

Thank you so much in advance!

sarah

Comment: Is there a mistake here? The two pieces of code look identical. Am I missing something? At any rate, I would be surprised if the binds were allowed in MySQL DDL statements. Why not just write the SQL as a string ?

Comment: Can you provide exactly what error message you get?